# One Material not rendering

Tags: rendering

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Render view shows the material, while the final render does not, and it is only one material (black plastic renders a standard while clay).[image: Render Preview in Viewport] [image: Final Render]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your materials tab and/or compositing tree?

Comment: [Nodes & Materials 1](https://imgur.com/a/at1yF)
[Nodes & Materials 2](https://imgur.com/a/XgVjj)
[Render Setup 1](https://imgur.com/a/Qn9z1)
[Render Setup 2](https://imgur.com/a/I8748)
[Render Setup 3](https://imgur.com/a/97IY5)

Comment: It looks like the normals on your object are inverted. Try recalculating them in edit mode with Ctrl N and see if that does anything. I can't imagine it would though. Other thing to check is if there is a material in the Material Override slot in the Render Layers tab.

Comment: They did need to be recalculated but it still didn't change the final render.
[Normals Reset + Render](https://imgur.com/a/CYzFp)

Comment: Did you check the render Layers tab to see if there was a Material in the Override slot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

A couple of the node settings were set way too high and applying the effect over too great an area making it appear as though there was a white material over the whole thing.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Check your material window again, under the selection area, make sure it is set to Data, not Object.

[image: object]

[image: data]

thats about all I can help without the file :) hope it works!

Comment: In his post he says that it shows correctly in the rendered view, while your suggestion causes rendered view to not show the material.

Comment: Hence my request for the file??? I attempted to provide as much a description as I could without proper information.

Comment: From the question though it is clear that your solution won't work. If you want to request a file it's better to add a comment to the question with such a request.

Comment: Screenshots posted in response to Brenticus' original answer